# Inserting of Notes using Workbench

Tags: workbench, notes

When I try to insert a note using Workbench, I get the following error: "UNKNOWN ERROR: Too many object types to load: 146." with the following fields rendered:

- Body
- IsPrivate
- OwnerID
- ParentID

If I try to use upsert, I notice the following fields being rendered with no issue:

- ID
- Body
- IsPrivate
- OwnerID
- Title

I believe something is wrong with Workbench being able to interpret the Note object correctly. Can anyone else confirm?  Any suggestions on how to insert notes en masse into Salesforce?

Comment: Have you tried using Data Loader?

Comment: try diff versions of the API in Workbench (like older ones)

Answer (score 5):

I had a colleague figure out the solution.  In Workbench, go to Settings -> Data Management Options -> Enable Smart Lookup (unchecked).  By default for me, it was checked.  Once disabled, I can view and perform inserts to the object without issue.